# monacaのAndoroidアプリ設定でパッケージ名に"_"(アンダースコア)が使えない

Tags: monaca

本日作成したプロジェクトのパッケージ名にアンダースコアを含めると「×無効な文字が含まれています。」と表示され、登録できません。
何か情報をお持ちの方はおられないでしょうか？
Monacaの公式情報等調べましたが、該当の情報を見つけきれませんでした。

利用しているドメインは、日本インターネット協会 Java 部会のパッケージ名登録/利用サービスにより取得したものです。
「jp.gr.java_conf.xxx」となっています。

Answer (score 1):

iOSではアンダースコア、AndroidではハイフンがAppIDに含めることのできない禁止文字となっています。monacaではiOSとAndroidで共通のconfig.xmlを使用しているため、AppIDもiOSとAndroidで共通になります。そのため、アプリ設定画面ではハイフンもアンダースコアも一括でバリデーションエラーとしているようです。

アプリ設定画面ではなくconfig.xmlを直接編集することで任意の文字列をAppIDに指定できますので、そちらを試してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: cither様 ご回答ありがとうございます。
試してみたいと思います。 以下独り言ですので、回答不要です。
以前作成したアプリについては同様な設定で問題なかったのでチェックが厳しくなったのでしょうか。
しかしながら、そのアプリの設定ではエラーはでませんし、いったん消して入力し直しても大丈夫でした。(登録はしていませんが。)
私は今のところAndroidオンリーなので、ちょっと使いづらいですね。
別々に設定できるようにするとか、警告のみにするとかなりませんかねぇ。

Comment: 以前はiOS用とAndroid用のconfig.xmlがそれぞれ存在したのですが、いつからか1ファイルに統合されたという経緯があります。おそらく、フォルダ構造を見てconfig.xmlがiosやandroidフォルダの下にあれば旧来のルールで、www直下にあれば新ルールで処理されるという風になっているのだと思います。